# Rule-specific wildcards in Snakemake

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I often find when adding rules to my workflow that I need to split large jobs up into batches. This means that my input/output files will branch out across temporary sets of batches for some rules before consolidating again into one input file for a later rule. For example:

```
rule all:
   input:
       expand("final_output/{sample}.counts",sample=config["samples"]) ##this final output relates to blast rule in that it will feature a column defining transcript type

...


rule batch_prep:
    input: "transcriptome.fasta"
    output:expand("blast_input_{X}.fasta",X=[1,2,3,4,5])
    script:"scripts/split_transcriptome.sh"

rule blast:
    input:"blast_input_{X}.fasta",
    output:"output_blast.txt"
    script:"scripts/blastx.sh"


...




rule rsem:
    input:
        "transcriptome.fasta",
        "{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "final_output/{sample}.counts"
    script:
        "scripts/rsem.sh"
```

In this simplified workflow, `snakemake -n` would show a separate `rsem` job for each sample (as expected, from wildcards set in rule `all`). However, `blast` would give a `WildcardError` stating that

```
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'X'
```

This makes sense, but I can't figure out a way for the `Snakefile` to submit separate jobs for each of the 5 batches above using the one `blast` template rule. I can't make separate rules for each batch, as the number of batches will vary on the size of the dataset. It seems it would be useful if I could define wildcards local to a rule. Does such a thing exist, or is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: "from wildcards set in rule all": Note that this is not really the case. Wildcards are determined by matching a desired file name with a rule's output pattern. When you use `expand` in the input of rule `all`, you generate a list of fully determined file names. Those file names do not carry with them a `sample` wildcard. The `sample` wildcard is re-created when those file names are matched with the pattern described in the output of rule `rsem`. You can use pattern `final_output/{elpmas}.counts` in `rsem` output, and it should work the same, even if expand in the input of `all` uses `sample`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly, if not, feel free to correct me:

So, you want to call the `rule blast` for every `"blast_input_{X}.fasta"`?
Then, the batch wildcard would need to be carried over into the output.

```
rule blast:
    input:"blast_input_{X}.fasta",
    output:"output_blast_{X}.txt"
    script:"scripts/blastx.sh"
```

If you then later want to merge the batches again in another rule, just use `expand` in the input of that rule.

```
input: expand("output_blast_{X}.txt", X=your_batches)
output: "merged_blast_output.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes that is what I needed to do.